# Can I use Slice with findAll method : Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

What i want : skip the count query that spring performs with `findAll(Pageable)`.

I found that there is [`Slice` datatype](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) for such UIs (next based) where there is no need for total records/pages hence no need for count query.

I can use `Slice` return type for methods like `findByName(Pageable)` etc
but if i use Slice for findAll(Pageable) then it still performs the count query.

Is there a workaround where i am able to use slice for `findAll` avoiding the count query?

P.S. : i want the features that slice provide like - hasNext, size etc
and i don't need to use Specification as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder, how spring is supposed to know there is a next if there's no count?

Comment: from what i know, you can always ask for one more record that asked for, say 20 were asked and you query for 21 and if you get 21 then you can say there is another page. :)

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to use [`Slice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) with [`findAll()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAll--) - you just need to extend the correct Spring JPA Repository.

It won't work if you extend [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html), because it extends [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) and there's already [`findAll(Pageable pageable)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method defined in the Paging repository.

If you extend [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) then you will be able to define method `Slice<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` in your repository.

Answer (score 5):

You can use query derivation for this.
Based on a [Spring Data JPA examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/34fe9d2720e9402db7708b9101011266d9e00d5a/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/simple/SimpleUserRepository.java):

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link Slice} counting a maximum number of {@link Pageable#getPageSize()} users matching given criteria
 * starting at {@link Pageable#getOffset()} without prior count of the total number of elements available.
 * 
 * @param lastname
 * @param page
 * @return
 */
Slice<User> findByLastnameOrderByUsernameAsc(String lastname, Pageable page);
```

You can modify this to your needs by adding the following to your repository:

```
Slice<User> findBy(Pageable page);
```

Since it doesn't have any other condition it performs a `findAll` limited to a single page, but without a count query.

Comment: No, his mean Slice<User> findAll().

Comment: Alas the findBy trick doesn't work when you pass a specification, I had to define a new repository interface just for a single use.. But it's a nice trick anyway

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement where I had to skip the count query for performance benefits, finally, implemented the custom implementation of `Slice<T>` resultset construction as below, which will provide all the functionality supported by `Slice<T>` such as hasNext, size.

- Repository Class

```
@Repository
public class CommonRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T> Slice<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
        Root<T> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(entityClass);
        criteriaQuery.select(entityRoot);
        TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

//limit of the returning result
        int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
//calculating offset from page-number and page-size
        int offset = pageable.getPageNumber() > 0 ? pageable.getPageNumber() * pageSize : 0;
//https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/48597dca246178c0d7e6952425004849d3fb02c0/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L156
// always fetch additional one element and skip it based on the pageSize to know hasNext value
        query.setMaxResults(pageSize + 1);
        query.setFirstResult(offset);
        List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();
        boolean hasNext = pageable.isPaged() && resultList.size() > pageSize;
        return new SliceImpl<>(hasNext ? resultList.subList(0, pageSize) : resultList, pageable, hasNext);
    }
}
```

- Repository Test Class

```
/**
* This integration Test requires the following external dependencies to run:
* 1. MySQL
*/
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CommonRepositoryITest {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PhotoRepository photoRepository = null;

    @Autowired
    private CommonRepository commonRepository = null;

    @Test
    public void findAllTest() {
        //Data Setup
        String title = "BATMAN";
        String size = "300*300";
        List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Photo photo = Photo.builder().
            id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).
            title(title).
            size("300*300").
            thumbnailUrl("http://localhost:8080/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .url("http://localhost:8080/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).
            build();
            photos.add(photo);
        }
        photoRepository.saveAll(photos);

        List<Photo> resultList = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Photo", Photo.class).
            getResultList();

        boolean hasNext;
        int pageNumber = 0;
        int limit = 25;
        Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);
        int itemsToAssert = 0;
        do {
            Slice<Photo> photos = commonRepository.findAll(Photo.class, pageRequest);
            hasNext = photos.hasNext();
            itemsToAssert = itemsToAssert + photos.getNumberOfElements();
            pageNumber++;
            pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);
        } while (hasNext);
        Assertions.assertEquals(resultList.size(), itemsToAssert);
    }
}
```